# Find matching cell value in named range

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to find the matching cell value in a named range in my excel workbook (.vba). I know the value that I am looking for, and also know the name of the range, and when I run the code the first time it runs with no problem, but on the second run with a new range name, I get an error.

I have tried a couple different ways to search the named range, and both ways result with the same error. The error is: "Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed".

**My initial code that I tried is:**

```
'march through the list of racks
For i = iFirstRackRow To iLastRackRow
    iCurrRackSize = Sheets("PLC I-O").Cells(i, 6).value
    iHardwareIndexEnd = iHardwareIndex + iCurrRackSize - 1
    rngCardsName = Trim(Sheets("PLC I-O").Cells(i, 2).value & "Cards")
    'march through the rack hardware
    For j = iHardwareIndex To iHardwareIndexEnd
        modCardSize = 0

        'march through each card in the rack
        For Each zCell In Range(rngCardsName)
            If zCell = Sheets("PLC I-O").Cells(j, 2) Then
                modCardSize = Sheets("Links").Cells(zCell.Row, zCell.Column + 1).value
                Exit For
            End If
        Next zCell

        If modCardSize <> 0 Then
            'io module matched
            NumRows = NumRows + modCardSize
        Else
            'processor or adapter module found
            NumRows = NumRows + 1
        End If
    Next
    iHardwareIndex = iHardwareIndex + iCurrRackSize
Next
```

**Or I have also tried:**

```
Dim rngFoundCell As Range
    With Range(rngCardsName)
        Set rngFoundCell = .Find(What:=Sheets("PLC I-O").Cells(j, 2).value, _
                            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
        If Not rngFoundCell Is Nothing Then
            'cell match was found
            rngrow = rngFoundCell.Row
            rngcol = rngFoundCell.Column
            modCardSize = Sheets("Links").Cells(rngrow, rngcol + 1).value
        Else
            'cell match was not found
        End If
    End With
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Please help.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this code? I only skimmed it, but is it possible that you don't even need VBA?  I.e., built in formulas (`vlookup`, `countifs`, etc) might be adequate?

Comment: Where have you set `Range(rngCardsName)` - you may want to be using `Range("rngCardsName")` if `rngCardsName` is the actual name of the range, rather than a variable

Comment: Try `Sheets("PLC I-O").Range(rngCardsName)` instead of just `Range(rngCardsName)` I am assuming that `rngCardsName = Trim(Sheets("PLC I-O").Cells(i, 2).value & "Cards")` returns a valid range name.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is the *After:=* parameter of your *.Find* . Try to change the parameter with the value `After:=.Cells(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone! I found this issue. It was the Trim instruction. Since there were multiple spaces in the Sheets("PLC I-O").Cells(i,2).value, I needed to use a custom function to make sure all spaces were removed.